# Can i put a cond inside an else of another cond?

Tags: scheme, racket

i´m writing a program to find out the solution for the logarithm of any base in Racket.

my question is, can I put a `cond` inside an `else` of another `cond`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes but it's unnecessary nesting:

```
(cond (predicate1 consequent1)
      (else (cond (predicate2 consequent2) 
                  (else alternative))))
```

Is the very same as:

```
(cond (predicate1 consequent1)
      (predicate2 consequent2) 
      (else alternative))
```

Only more readable. If it didn't we might as well just have `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - certainly. See the Guide for some examples.
 http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/conditionals.html#%28part._cond%29